# Guardar en una sesión los datos de un formulario en PHP

Tags: php

Por ejemplo: el registro de usuarios quiero recuperarlos más adelante, si el usuario regresa a la página del mismo, tengo el formulario pero no se como quardar en una variable de session y recuperarlo despues.

```
<form method="post" action="formtemp.php">
<input type="text" name="nombres" placeholder="Nombre" />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes guardar los datos de la siguiente forma (Esto iría en el action del formulario)

```
<?php 
session_start(); //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente

//Agregamos variables a la sesión
$_SESSION['nombres'] = isset($_POST['nombres']) ? $_POST['nombres'] : null;
$_SESSION['email'] = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$_SESSION['password'] = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
```

Ahora para comprobar podemos usar `isset()` y validar que los campos existan y no sean nulos, para ello podemos crear una función tipo:

```
function session_exists(){
     return isset($_SESSION['nombres']) &&
            isset($_SESSION['email']) && 
            isset($_SESSION['password']);
}
```

Ahora, esto no es recomendable ya que las variables de sesión pueden sobrescribirse si trabajas las variables en diferentes contextos y pestañas.

Puedes leer más de las variables de sesión en la documentación de php en [este enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

Un buen uso para la variable de sesión es guardar un boolean para saber si el usuario está logueado y quizá un objeto de dicho usuario para poder reconocerlo.

Comment: Algo importante que debes  poner al principio es la declaracion de <?php
  // inicia la session
  session_start();
?> para que el php entienda que estas usando variables de session

Comment: @AlexanderRodrigez Gracias por la sugerencia, he complementado la respuesta para que sea de más utilidad a everson

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender tu problema, pero primero unas aclaraciones:

1. La variable $_SESSION, no la usas para almacenar información de un formulario, en cambio empleala para traer el id de tu usuario desde la base de datos, y su sintaxis seria de la siguiente manera:

   *$id_usuario_actual = $_SESSION['id_usuario_registrado'];*

Donde *id_usuario_registrado* es el nombre de la columna de tu tabla de usuarios, y ese valor de la sesion actual lo almaceno en este caso dentro de la variable de PHP *id_usuario_actual*

2. Ahora también debes saber como realizar consultas a una base de datos con PHP, para traer la información del usuario que tiene la sesión iniciada actualmente.
3. Las validaciones de los campos que deseas almacenar tambien son importantes, así tu definas el tipo de dato a ingresar en cada campo () un usuario malicioso puede vulnerar facilmente un sitio web si no se tienen en cuenta cierto estándares de seguridad informática.

Considero que deberias ver la siguiente lista de reproducción en YouTube:  **Aprende a crear una página web (PHP para principiantes, curso completo)** del canal de **Java Dev One**.

Eso para el caso de aprender PHP puro en primera instancia, para que una vez entendido como funciona PHP, trabajar con frameworks (herramientas que facilitan la programación) como Laravel o Symfony. (aunque también puedes optar por aprender un framework de PHP sin necesidad de ver como funciona el PHP puro).

Comment: Tu respuesta está basada en opiniones, Puedes leer "Respondiendo" https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda he conseguido hacer funcionar mi sistema con vuestras orientaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Te envio este codigo que puede servirte de ayuda para resolver tu problema, aqui puedes ver el uso de la **$_SESSION** en cuanto a su asignacion, lectur y destruccion de contenido.

1) Lo primero es el codigo del formulario el cual el primer bloque de php es para iniciar el uso de la **SESSION**, el cual siempre debes colocarlo en cualquier codigo que use este recurso.

2) Luego se asignan a variable de php los valores de las variables de **$_SESSION** pero como puede ser que sea la primera vez, estas no tiene un valor definido y por eso se hace uso del **isset()**  para indicar si tiene contenido se asigna de lo contrario se deja en blanco.

3) El formulario recibe los valores de los datos de $_SESSION a travez de las variables **$nombre / $email** las cuales usan el atributo **value=""** para colocar el contenido.

```
  <?php
  // inicia la session
    session_start();
  ?>


  <?php 
  // asignacion de variable session 
  // si no existe la session pone un valor '' 
  $nombre = isset($_SESSION['nombre'])? $_SESSION['nombre'] : '';
  $email = isset($_SESSION['email'])? $_SESSION['email'] : '';

  ?>

<form method="post" action="formtemp.php">
<input type="text" name="nombres" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php  echo $nombre; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"  value="<?php  echo $email; ?>" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario" />
</form>
```

EL segundo archivo es el que cargara los valores recibido por el $_POST

1) Al igual que el anterior, se debe declarar al principio la variable **session_start();** para su uso.

2) El otro fragmento de codigo es el que asigna los valores recibido por el **$_POST[]** a las variables de **$_SESSION[]**.

3) Aqui se colocan dos link, uno para retornar a la pagina del formulario: **form.php** y el otro es para destruir la session: **destruirsession.php**

```
  <?php
  // inicia la session
    session_start();
  ?>

  <?php
    // cargar variable de seccion con valors post
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombres'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
  ?>

  <h3>Session asignada</h3>
  <a href="form.php">Retornar al formulario</a>

  <h3>Destruir Session</h3>
  <a href="destruirsession.php">Destruir la Session</a>
```

EL ultimo archivo es opcional y sirve para borrar el contenido de la variable de $_SESSION[], lo he colocado para demostrar que al borrarse la informacion el contenido desaparece.

```
<?php
  // inicia la session
  session_start();


  // Finalmente, destruir la sesión.
  session_destroy();
?>

<h3>Session destruida</h3>
<a href="form.php">Returnar al formulario</a>
```